# ArcGIS Javascipt Api Printing

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing

I've got a webpage which prints a web map via the ArcGIS Javascript API.
The DPI of the print is 72. To debug I added three different types of symbols
 1. The default (most of them are)
 2. One custom symbol created at large scale
 3. A red icon created by ArcGIS

As you can see on the image it looks really pixel imperfect. While the background is nice, you can almost count the pixels in the symbols.

Does anyone has some kind of idea what's causing the pixelastion of the symbols and how to avoid that?
[image]

Comment: I am not sure but you need to check REST service at your end for print task. Sometimes default  setting are used. Did you tried sample service by ArcGIS ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to increase you DPI and take a look at this, it has more do to with legends, but it my apply to your problem: http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40538